# FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON still results in dim screen

Tags: android

In my Android activity, I set `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`flag as shown here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    ...
}
```

Despite this, my screen goes dim after a few minutes of inactivity.

I am wondering if there is a better way to ensure that the screen does not dim. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution, but the Android docs say that [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

> as long as this window is visible to the user, keep the device's
>   screen turned on and bright.

I also made a sample app just by adding this piece of line in the activity and it worked. I let the app be as is for more than 5 min and didn't dim at all. I'm guessing there is something else going wrong with your code. Are you in the exact same activity when the brightness decreases?

The other thing you can try is using [WakeLocks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) (NOT RECOMMENDED). But note that its not a good practice to use it (at least just for your requirement for screen brightness purposes). You can find the code for the same [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu). You should also take a look at [this blog](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-keep-screen-onawake-3-possible-ways/) which talks about the 3 ways for letting the screen on.